# Залинковать CSS и HTML файл

Tags: html, css

Не получается привязать CSS к ХТМЛу.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://stena38.ru/adm/css/css.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="block1">
 <div id="menu"> 
  <div id="new_z"> Новые заказы </div>
  <div id="obr_z"> Заказы в обработке </div>
  <div id="old_z"> Обработанные заказы </div>
  <div id="dobtov"> Добавить товар </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Это Индекс.

```html
    .menu {
background:red;
padding:5px;
}
```

Это файл CSS
Точку перед меню убирал, с кавычками экспериментировал. По ссылке все открывается. Если ставить прямо в файл - то все работает. А ссылкой ни в какую. Вот что может быть еще такое?

Comment: в разметке у тебя id, а в css ты к классу пытаешься обратиться. Поменяй точку на # и все заработает

Comment: Спасибо. Целый день бился над этой ерундой. Но тогда почему если сделать одним файлом то все рабоатет?

Comment: Что значит _если сделать одним файлом_? Не видя как именно ты пробовал - нельзя ничего сказать, может ты как раз и пробовал с #

Answer (score -2):

Это будет работать, если css и html в одной папке

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Если они в разных папках, то надо указать путь от файла html к css

Для привязки стиля к стилевому идентификатору элемента используется символ "#"

Например:

```
css: #idname{...}
html: <div id="idname">...</div>
```

Comment: у автора проблема не в этом. Он файл по абсолютному пути загружает.

Comment: @Grundy Я уже понял.. автор через минуту после моего ответа добавил html к вопросу ))

Comment: не добавил, а просто форматирование поправил.

Comment: тем не менее вопросы _не добавляется **link** на css_ и _не применяется css_ разные. ответ был дан на первый, мог бы и не минусовать..

Comment: мог бы, если бы ответ отвечал на вопрос. Но данный ответ - вообще никак к вопросу не относится